# Spring Boot или Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, mvc, boot

Закончил свой первый проект на Spring Boot.
Установил его на сервер у себя на фирме - все работает, все счастливы.

По сему вопрос: почему Spring Boot позиционируется как "для новичков"? Почему его нельзя использовать как готовый самодостаточный проект и какие минусы по сравнению со стандартным Spring MVC war?

Comment: Где он позиционируется как "для новичков"? Также IMHO подобные очень общие вопросы не для этого сайта, а для форума какого-нибудь.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нужно, в первую очередь, разделять задачи, которые решают Spring Boot и Spring MVC.

- Spring Boot - это инструмент, который позволяет при минимальных усилиях создать свое приложение, будь то web-проект или что либо ещё.
- Spring MVC - это часть Spring Framework`а, которая отвечает за создание именно mvc-проекта.

Spring Boot удобен для новичков тем, что путем несложной конфигурации можно получить полностью рабочее приложение-болванку, которую без проблем можно расширить. Использовать его можно, просто он привнесет множество вещей, которые вам не потребуются. Если говорить о более-менее серьезных продуктах, которые вы разрабатываете - это не правильно, и в дальнейшем, скорее всего, вам придется выкидывать их из проекта.

Imho, Spring Boot идеален для всякого рода прототипов, когда нужно максимально быстро сделать рабочее приложение, чтобы показать/проверить/протестировать/провести исследование. В серьезных приложениях или при дальнейшем развитии будет проще и правильнее использовать те инструменты, которые вам действительно нужны, а не все подряд.

Comment: Нет ну если продолжить Вашу логическую цепочку, то и Spring "тянет" много лишнего и тогда JavaEE наше все?

Comment: Если вы работаете над серьёзным enterprise - то, представьте себе, да, JavaEE это наше всё. Spring как фреймворк позволяет вам не заморачиваться с решением типовых проблем. А Spring Boot позволяет также не заморачиваться и со сборкой, окружением и тд. А вот нужно ли тащить в ваш проект кучу кода в виде зависимостей - это уже решать вам.